# Codename one marshmallow authorization

Tags: android, codenameone, opentok

I am trying to get the camera and micro permissions on Android. I added in the codenameone_library_required.properties file :

```
android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="true"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" android:required="true"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="true"/>
```

This works for older versions of Android, but not in for Marshmallow as expected. Thus, I read on the codename one developer guide that to ask for permissions in later android version I have to target sdk 23. Indeed, I added in the build hints :

```
android.targetSDKVersion=23
```

But Unfortunately this is not sufficient and when I launch the application it does not ask for the permissions.

Should I add something to ask for permissions? Maybe the "Display.getInstance().setProperty(...)" ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i really understood your question, you should request camera permission at runtime (android Marshmallow and above) like this:

```
//to check if the user grant the permission before
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    //if it is not the case, request new permission
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},requestCode);
    return;
}

//your camera code is here
```

in Codename One's case, as @mina said, you couldn't find ActivityCompat class, so try this chunk of code:

```
if(!com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.checkForPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, "This should be the description shown to the user...")){

// you didn't get the permission, you might want to return here
}
// you have the permission, do what you need
```

Comment: I don't think that I have access to the ActivityCompat from codename one, but I might be wrong.

Comment: try this [link](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/marshmallow-permissions-in-the-simulator-and-native-code.html)

Comment: Yes and it's also covered in the developer guide